# Get authorisation token after HttpServletRequest.login()

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, websphere-8, ltpa

In our webapplication we need to store the authentication token (LtpaToken2 (websphere), JSESSIONID(tomcat)) in an external datastore after a successful login. I was hoping to retrieve the token after a login on the HttpServletRequest object.

```
        LOG.debug("nr of cookies in request " + request.getCookies().length + " response header " + response.getHeaderNames().size());
        request.login(employee.getUsername(), employee.getPassword());
        URI uri = info.getBaseUri().resolve("/login2");
        LOG.debug("new uri is: '"+ uri + "' nr of cookies in request " + request.getCookies().length + " response header " + response.getHeaderNames().size());
        // Add the Higgs Cookie
```

The log output indicates an unchanged number of cookies an headers. Is there another way to retrieve the authentication token in the same request as the login is done, preferable platform independent? I probably can do a redirect and read the token out of the next request but I'm afraid this will impose some extra security threats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason why you want to store that cookie? As it changes after the certain timeout, so storing it doesn't provide much value. Below code that you can use to access it from request.

Authentication token is a cookie not a header. You have to access it using the following code (this code works in any page AFTER successful authentication) :

```
Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
for(Cookie c : cookies){
    if("LtpaToken2".equals(c.getName())) {
        // do something with ltpa cookie
        out.println(c.getName() + " : " + c.getValue());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
To get token in the servlet that performs login use the following code:

```
Set<Object> credentials = WSSubject.getRunAsSubject().getPrivateCredentials();
for (Object credential : credentials) {
    if(credential instanceof SingleSignonToken) {
        SingleSignonToken token = (SingleSignonToken)credential;
        System.out.println(token.getName());
        System.out.println(token.getUniqueID());
        System.out.println(token.getPrincipal());
        System.out.println("LTPA Token encoded: " + Base64.encode(token.getBytes()));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very good question. Let's call it management interference. I tried the solution you gave, but that fails (i'll update the question).

Comment: As a matter of fact for Websphere the authentication tokens don't time out, and users can stay logged for eternity, we're battling this by storing the cookies and registering last touch time etc. Obviously we're not willing to spend a nickel on an IBM solution for this behavior.

Comment: @drjerry Yes, it doesn't work in the servlet just after login, sorry I didn't read fully your question. I'll update answer. This works in any page after successful login. But regarding the other part, ltpatoken by default is valid for 2 hours. After that you will have to relogin.